# Custom Validation on HTML Number Input Misbehaving

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, cross-browser

In putting together a small webapp, I'm trying to ensure that end users are unable to place invalid characters in a number field that can hold signed floats.  I'm using Dojo to search on an applied CSS class (in this case, `ogInputNumber`) and set events on input, keyup, and blur.

Ideally, I would like the input to be `type="number"` and to only allow digits, a hyphen (for signed floats), and a period character to act as a decimal place.  If a user includes more than one hyphen or period character, the JS should truncate that second invalid character and everything thereafter in the input.  Unfortunately, the JS behaves differently depending on whether the input is `type="number"` or `type="text"`.

For `type="text"`, if I attempt to enter the text `2.6a`, `2.6` is fine, but the `a` is caught on the input event and prevented from appearing in the input.  This is the desired behavior, but I would like to have the input as `type="number"` so the number spinners appear and for ease of use with mobile devices (so the number keyboard is brought up by default).

For `type="number"`, if I attempt to enter the text `2.6a`, the `2.6` is allowed to remain, but as soon as `a` is typed, the entire field is cleared out.  That will prevent any invalid characters, but it's annoyingly overzealous.  I've replicated this behavior on Chrome, Firefox, IE11, and Opera.

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to why the JS operates differently between inputs with `type="text"` and those with `type="number"`?

HTML:

```
<p>
    <label for="numberInput1">Text Input</label>
    <input id="numberInput1" class="ogInputNumber" type="text" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="numberInput2">Number Input</label>
    <input id="numberInput2" class="ogInputNumber" type="number" />
</p>
```

JS:

```
// Checks number input fields for proper formatting
require(["dojo/domReady!", "dojo/on", "dojo/query"],

function (ready, on, query) {
    query(".ogInputNumber").forEach(function (node) {
        // Replace all the non-numeric, non-period, and non-hyphen characters with nothing while the user is typing
        on(node, "input, keyup", function () {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d\.-]/g, '');
        });
        // When the user leaves the input, format it properly as a signed float (or zero if it's something weird)
        on(node, "blur", function () {
            try {
                if (this.value) {
                    this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toString();
                } else {}
            } catch (error) {
                this.value = 0;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/etehy6o6/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's the default behavior of number input type, but I'm not sure. It's logical to think the input should not let the user put anything that is not a number, so it clears all the value before you can fire your keyup event.

So to keep the last valid value declare a variable outside the scope of your event and set it to the replaced value that was not cleared because invalid key input.

Using the code in your Fiddle:

**Edited because addressed bug in comments**

#### HTML

```
<!-- I asigned default values to test other scenarios -->
<p>
    <label for="numberInput1">Text Input</label>
    <input id="numberInput2" class="ogInputNumber" type="text" value="3.1416" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="numberInput">Number Input</label>
    <input id="numberInput" class="ogInputNumber" type="number" value="3.1416" />
</p>
```

#### Javascript

```
// Checks number input fields for proper formatting
require(["dojo/domReady!", "dojo/on", "dojo/query"],

function (ready, on, query) {
    query(".ogInputNumber").forEach(function (node) {
        var validValue = this.value;
        // Replace all the non-numeric, non-period, and non-hyphen characters with nothing while the user is typing
        on(node, "input, keyup", function () {
            if (this.value == '' && validValue.length > 1) {
                this.value = validValue;
            }
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d\.-]/g, '');
            validValue = this.value;
        });
        // When the user leaves the input, format it properly as a signed float (or zero if it's something weird)
        on(node, "blur", function () {
            try {
                if (this.value) {
                    this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toString();
                } else {}
            } catch (error) {
                this.value = 0;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That partially addresses the issue, but the above code will prevent me from removing any values that exist in the field.  e.g., if there is a `7` in the field on page load, I am unable to delete it and make the value null.

Comment: You're right! I edited the answer and put default values in the HTML that appear on page load. Now by checking the length when you leave the input empty you can protect it from being cleared if you insert an invalid character after a number.

Comment: Excellent - the only issue now is that the field isn't accepting hyphens (for signed ints, etc.).  I think this might be a harder limit on `input type="number"`, but I'll do some research.  Thanks for your help, @Salvador